# How to install R package from hosted Git repo

Tags: r

I want to install the R package from Git repo but it's not GitHub and not BitBucket. It's a different domain that is in fact BitBucket on an intranet. Is there a way to install from that URL? I don't want to create a zip file and commit to the git repo.

I've found [devtools::install_url](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.6/topics/install_url)

but when I use it I've got an error:

```
Downloading package from URL: 
https://bitbucket.example.com/stash/projects/PROJECT/repos/package
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  Don't know how to decompress files with extension
```

So it seems that a zip file is the only option for devtools to install a package. Is there any other way to install a package from a URL that is git repo that is not public GitHub or BitBucket?

Comment: Maybe try `remotes::install_bitbucket` and set the `host=` parameter to your specific URL? It's hard to say when we can't actually see the repo to test.

Comment: This does not seem to be a [tag:git] question. The only useful thing I can say from the Git side is that `git archive` can generate a zip file *from* a repository. You would have to hook that up to whatever Git *server* you're using, though: some URL or other method would have to wind up *invoking* `git archive` to make the zip file. That would probably be a question about the web server you're using.

Comment: @torek it's not helpful because I can just use `git clone`  and  `R CMD INSTALL .`.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the suggesting, will try to tomorrow.